# Typescript recursive types for array of array

Tags: typescript

I want describe some data as where a value in the array could be another array of numbers, this is done indefinitely so the types should be recursive.

With the following code I receive an error

`Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Data'`

```
type Data = ReadonlyArray<number> | Data[];
const data: Data = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]];
```

How to fix it using the latest TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

```
type E = number

type ListOfE = E[]

type NestedListOfE = (E | NestedListOfE)[]

const a: E = 10
const b: ListOfE = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
const c: NestedListOfE = [ 1, 2, [ 3, [ 4, 5 ] ] ]
```

Note usage of recursive types is only available since TS 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript treats an array type of unions and unions of array very differently. Something like `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]` is actually of type `(number | number[])[]` - which **is not** assignable to `number[] | number[][]`.

This means that you need an array of unions, where the union can circularly reference itself.

```
type Data = readonly (number | Data)[];
```

The above will declare a readonly array of the recursive atom, `number`. Now you'll be able to assign `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]]`

Try it out on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UBOE4BMD2A7AGxCgAo8BXAWwCMI0oAfWBOASgG0BdAbgCheAxvgDOwKFhYAuZohRR2ARgA0UAEwqAzCvYAWFQFZtANhUB2Thb5A)

Comment: what about this `type Data = ReadonlyArray<number | Data>;` ? WDYT?

Comment: what is the difference between readonly and  ReadonlyArray here? they should be equivalent no?

Comment: @Radex `readonly number[]` is the same as `ReadonlyArray<number>` - `readonly` as a keyword is just more general, you can use `ReadonlyArray<number | Data>` just fine.